# Empty Workingset

Tags: c#, winforms

is using empty working set or forcing GC collects a recommended practices in trying to reduce memory versus performance.  is there any articles or best practices to help understand the implications of using this functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pestering those functions is definitely a good practice. GC is smart enough when it comes to collecting garbage and will promptly release all the unused memory it reserved previosly when asked to do so by the OS.